# Parse Cloud Code Promise error handling

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I'm kind of new to JS and really new to Promises.

Let's say I have a chain of promises:

```
//var challenge is created before all this

isUserInCooldown().then( function(hoursRemaining) 
{
    if (hoursRemaining > 0) 
    {
        return Parse.Promise.error("You can't challenge 'cuz you're on cooldown.");
    }

    var objectsToSave = [];

    //DO SOME STUFF TO THE OBJECTS

    return Parse.Object.saveAll(objectsToSave);

}).then( function(list)
{
    //DO SOME STUFF TO CHALLENGE

    return challenge.save(null);

}).then( function(challenge) 
{
    return Parse.Promise.as(challenge);
},
function(error) 
{
    if (theSaveAllFailed) { return "Couldn't save all"; }
    if (theSaveFailed) { return "Couldn't save the challenge"; }
    //etc.
});
```

I am refactoring a bunch of code that used callbacks and each `error: function(error) {}` returned a custom error message.  I want to be able to pass a custom error message depending on where the chain broke down.

I figure it has something to do with [fail() or reject()](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Promise.html#methods_fail) but I haven't figured out how.

I would like to know:

1: How can I return custom error messages like I want to?

2: Am I using promises correctly (based on what you see here?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to override the error message of a promise rejection, you *can* use `.fail` to add handlers as you suspected.
2. While your promises would function as written, they could be tidied up:

   - `isUserInCooldown` should include the `hoursRemaining > 0` check so it doesn't pollute other functions.
   - If `challenge.save` doesn't depend on `objectsToSave`, firing them both off simultaneously and using `Parse.Promise.when` would be faster.
   - You never call `response.success` or `response.error` as cloud functions require.

What you did here is pointless, as I repeat to prove a point:

```
.then(function(challenge){
  return Parse.Promise.as(challenge);
}).then(function(challenge){
  return Parse.Promise.as(challenge);
}).then(function(challenge){
  return Parse.Promise.as(challenge);
});
```

Ah, much better:

```
isUserInCooldown().then( function() {
  return Parse.Object.saveAll(objectsToSave).fail(function(){
    return "Couldn't save all";
  });
}).then( function(){
  return challenge.save().fail(function(){
    return "Couldn't save the challenge";
  });
}).then(response.success, response.error)
```

Or, if you're not using cloud functions:

```
.fail(function(error) {
  console.log(error); //logs "Couldn't save all" or "Couldn't save the challenge"
});
```